# problem 8 project euler ,Can anyone explain to me?

Tags: python, python-3.x, project

Question:
The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

I can not understand this question.
Can anyone explain to me?

Comment: Every chain of numbers in this string has a product. You must find the chain with the maximum product.It is given for 4-numbers-chain and you must find it for 13-numbers-chain

Comment: You must scan through the given number sequence to find the sequence of 13 digits which have the largest product and report the result of that product.  Taking a smaller example: Given the number sequence '2,7,5,2, 4'  the product of the 2 number sequence in the string is 35, since 5*7 = 35 and it is the largest 2 number product in the string

Answer (score 0):

The question wants you to go from the front to the back of the string and find the maximum product. You could load that 1000 digit number into a string.

```
reallyLongNum = "731...450"#get your big string of numbers into this somehow, careful of spaces
product = 0

for ...:#loop through all the values
    digits = ...#substring of the really long number that you care about
    tmpProduct = 1

    for ...: #every letter in the digits substring
        tmpProduct = #calcualte the product of the letters

    if ...: #the tmpProduct is greater than previous highest product
        product = tmpProduct 

#you now have the largest product
```

Don't want to give you a solution but this might help you make your own.

So if the `reallyLongNum` string was `"1110123110111331110"`, and you only wanted it for a number made by multiplying 3 digits you could step through and do the following.

1. Your loop would start off with `digits` equaling `"111"` and
   calculate a product of `1`.
2. On the next loop it would get a product
   of 0 because `digits` equals `0`.
3. Three loops later, `digits` would equal `"123"` and make a product of `6` which is now your largest product.
4. Then nine loops later, `digits` would be `"133"` and a product of `9` and replace the old maximum of `6`.
5. On the next loop it would once again calculate a product of `9` but you don't need to replace the maximum product.
6. You should stop before the end when you reach `"110"`.

Try making a solution with smaller sets of numbers and breaking the problem into steps. You may find it useful to know how to [convert between strings and numbers](https://realpython.com/convert-python-string-to-int/). as well as [for loops and ranges](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) and [strings and their substrings](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings.asp).